# uploading app to app store - mach-o header code 0x72613c21

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store

I'm trying to publish my app to the app store. 
I have all the certificates etc. needed. 
When I try to archive and then validate the project, I get this error message:
[image]

## This is the code that was returned to me:

## A file called "IDEDistribution.critical.log"

*2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] Failed to generate distribution items with error: Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=0 "Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=}
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] Presenting: Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=0 "Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=}*

## IDEDistribution.standard.log :

*2017-01-22 00:01:16 +0000 [MT] Beginning distribution assistant for archive: Steem Converter, task: Validate
2017-01-22 00:01:16 +0000 [MT] Automatically selecting the only availaable distribution method 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/Realm.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/Realm.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreMedia.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftQuartzCore.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/Charts.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/Charts.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreData.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreData.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/Pods_Steem_Converter.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/sirwinchester/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2017-01-22/Steem Converter 22.01.17, 00.55.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Steem Converter.app/Frameworks/Pods_Steem_Converter.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2017-01-22 00:01:44 +0000 [MT] Canceled distribution assistant*

## IDEDistribution.verbose.log

*2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at 
2017-01-22 00:01:17 +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init*

**I already saw that this question has been asked on stack before but none of the answers could help me fix my problem! 
Where is the problem here, what am I supposed to do ?!**

Answer (score 8):

Give this a try and see if this works...

[image]

Comment: I don't have this section but to occur the same error

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. It turns out that Apple has updated the program license agreement and you just have to accept it. It's a pity that after so many years, Xcode can't show some message instead of crashing.

The information on Apple Developer Account says:

> The program license agreement has been updated.
>
> [Owner] needs to accept the latest Apple Developer Program License
> Agreement for your team to continue integrating new technologies,
> submitting content to App Review, accessing Certificates, Identifiers
> and Profiles, and more.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community - Sorry, I disagree with your recommendation. This is part of the experience of being being in Apple Developer program. If the status of your "accepted terms" is out of date, a lot of things break across their tool chain.

Answer (score 0):

Also check if you accidentally copy frameworks via "Coby Bundle Resources" in your "Build Phases".

Answer (score 0):

In my case i fixed it with aligning version number of app with appstore connect.