# IOS Application validation failed Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, binaries

My app is building and running without errors, but when I try to archive and verify in Xcode as preparation to App Store submission I get this error:

Code signing "RestKit.framework" failed.

When I look in the logs I find this problem:

> Didn't find archived user entitlements for
>   :
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at
>   "/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2019-01-01/what
>   01-01-2019,
>   12.17.xcarchive/Products/Applications/what.app/Frameworks/RestKit.framework
>   did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at
>   "/Users/mihaimanea/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2019-01-01/what
>   01-01-2019,
>   12.17.xcarchive/Products/Applications/what.app/Frameworks/RestKit.framework"
>   did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}

I tried removing the embedded binary but then application is not running anymore.

Comment: Could you clear derive data and retry it again?

Comment: I just tried that did not help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41786330/uploading-app-to-app-store-mach-o-header-code-0x72613c21