# Manual integrated framework failed when distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, code-signing, codesign

i've integrated a third party framework into my tvOS project. The framework is integrated manually by pulling .framework file to Target -> Project -> General -> Embedded Binaries. And then i can compile and run my project, everything is good until i try to upload the build to app store, it failed to code sign the framework

[image]

Does anyone has bump into this situation before?

EDIT: Standard log as follow:

28-2-19, 2.43 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/test.app/Frameworks/raygun4apple.framework'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/hays/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2019-02-28/testTVApp 
28-2-19, 2.43 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/test.app/Frameworks/raygun4apple.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource."

Comment: Please check the logs (show logs button in bottom) and edit your post with that log, its more help full to get help.

Comment: @AmmaiappanUpdated

Comment: It may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/41787530/529294

Comment: @Ammaiappan i've seen this post before, but it is not the same issue

Answer (score 2):

The Raygun4Apple provider is developed as a “fat” library, which includes architectures for both simulators and devices. You will need to strip out the simulator architectures (x86_64, i386) before releasing. There is a helpful article on how to do this here: https://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/

so, you have to do:

- open xcode
- select your project
- navigate to the Build phases
- click + icon to add new phase: New run script phase
- move it behind the Embedded frameworks phase
- open your phase and paste the script from the article
- also select "run script only when installing"

now you can archive and sign your ipa

Comment: also if you decide to extract the script into separate file, don't forget about setting execution access to this file like: chmod -x <ur_file_name>